# When typing $( in visual studio for jquery... it gets automatically converted to $addHandler(

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, customization

Everytime I start typing $( to call a jquery command visual studio 2008 automatically converts that to: $addHandler( ... I have to delete that and retype it every single time.

Is there a way to fix this change it?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding JavaScript intellisense Ctrl+Shift+j.  It may not "see" the $ function yet.

Double check that  you have the javascript hotfix from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736), and that you have the vsDoc files referenced.